# escape ")" in windows batch "for" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

I need to iterate lines in a file. Following command doesn't work:

```
set filename=c:\program files (x86)\somewhere
...
for /f "delims==" %%i in (%filename%) do echo %%i
```

because of ")" in the filename. Error:

```
\somewhere) was unexpected at this time.
```

Escaping by "^" doesn't work here because I need to use an variable instead of inline filename. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the filename in double quotes, but also add the `usebackq` option:

```
set filename=c:\program files (x86)\somewhere
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%i in ("%filename%") do echo %%i
```

From the output of `FOR /?`:

```
usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
                  where a back quoted string is executed as a
                  command and a single quoted string is a
                  literal string command and allows the use of
                  double quotes to quote file names in
                  file-set.
```

Comment: @Mechaflash: Your answer is as correct as mine though, so +1 regardless. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
set filename=c:\program files (x86)\somewhere
...
for /f "USEBACKQ delims==" %%i in ("%filename%") do echo %%i
```

USEBACKQ allows you to use double quotes for paths with spaces